# Replace Object in Pandas Series by Attribute of the Object

Tags: python, pandas

Let's assume we have a Class Foo:

```
Class Foo:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

Now I have 2 of these Objects:

```
foo1 = Foo("foo")
foo2 = Foo("bar")
```

Now I have a pandas Series:

```
series = pd.Series([foo1, foo2])
```

Printing this one out gives:

```
0    <__main__.Foo object at 0x01500FB8>
1    <__main__.Foo object at 0x0151B118>

dtype: object
```

Is there any way to replace the Object by its attribute name?

The best way I came up with was turning the whole Series into a list and creating a dictionary of Object:Object.name for every item in the list and then using the replace function, but it felt like there should be an easier way to accomplish this.

I'd appreciate any suggestions, thank you.

Comment: df.some_col.apply(funcname)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestion of using "apply" I found the following solution:

```
series = series.apply(getattr, args=("name",))
```